# Activity crash if there is no entries

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a problem. When there is entries stats activity works correctly. But If there is NO entries  the stast activity crashes.
Please, help me. Need something to prevent it. 
(I'm not programmer, so  its not easy for me)

```
package com.sudarmuthu.android.wt.activities;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.sudarmuthu.android.wt.R;
import com.sudarmuthu.android.wt.data.DBUtil;
import com.sudarmuthu.android.wt.data.Entry;

/**
 * Activity class to handle stats
 * 

public class EntriesStatsActivity extends Activity {


// for debugging
private static boolean D = true;
private static String TAG = "WT - EntriesStatsActivity";

private List<Entry> mEntries;

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.app.Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
 */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.entry_stats);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    int typeId = bundle.getInt("typeId");

    if (D) Log.d(TAG, "Got type id: " + typeId);

    mEntries = DBUtil.fetchEntries(this, typeId, null);
    Entry firstEntry = mEntries.get(0);

    int count = mEntries.size();
    float sum = 0;
    float average = 0;

    float min = Float.parseFloat(firstEntry.getValue());
    float max = Float.parseFloat(firstEntry.getValue());

    // calculate
    for (Entry entry : mEntries) {
        float value = Float.parseFloat(entry.getValue());
        sum += value;

        if (value < min) {
            min = value;
        }

        if (value > max) {
            max = value;
        }
    }

    average = sum / count;

    // populate the values
    TextView statsCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.statsCount);
    statsCount.setText("" + count);

    TextView statsSum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.statsSum);
    statsSum.setText("" + sum);

    TextView statsAverage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.statsAverage);
    statsAverage.setText("" + average);

    TextView valueFrom = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.valueFrom);
    valueFrom.setText("" + min);

    TextView valueTo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.valueTo);
    valueTo.setText("" + max);

}
```

}

Comment: 12-17 16:20:36.563: W/dalvikvm(2326): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300) 12-17 16:20:36.613: E/AndroidRuntime(2326): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 12-17 16:20:36.613: E/AndroidRuntime(2326): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.training.programs/com.training.tracker.activities.EntriesStatsActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may get a null pointer exception :

```
mEntries = DBUtil.fetchEntries(this, typeId, null);
if( mEntries == null ) {
   return;
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't help:12-15 17:29:17.537: E/AndroidRuntime(3815): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-15 17:29:17.537: E/AndroidRuntime(3815): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.training.programs/com.training.tracker.activities.EntriesStatsActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

Answer (score 0):

If there is no Entries, `mEntries.size()` is equals to 0. So when you do

```
average = sum / count;
```

You divide by 0, which throws an `Arithmetic Exception`(you can't divide a number by 0).

Comment: Thanks, I did not even pay attention to it))